# How can a class A, that is a member of class B, share private members of class B?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

Master.h

```
#ifndef MASTER_H
#define MASTER_H

class Master
{
   friend class Friend;

   public:
      Master(void);
      ~Master(void);
      void CallFriendFunction(int largeData);

   private:
      int    largeData;

      //Want this class to share largeData;
      Friend testFriend;
};
#endif // MASTER_H
```

Master.cpp

```
#include "Master.h"

Master::Master(void)
{
   //Inentionally left blank
}

Master::~Master(void)
{
   //Intentionally left blank
}

void Master::CallFriendFunction(int largeData)
{
   this->largeData = largeData;
   this->testFriend.Test(this);
}
```

Friend.h

```
#ifndef FRIEND_H
#define FRIEND_H

#include "Master.h"

class Friend
{
   public:
      Friend(void);
      ~Friend(void);

      void Test(Master* masterPtr);
};

#endif // FRIEND_H
```

Friend.cpp

```
#include "Friend.h"
#include <iostream>

Friend::Friend(void)
{
   //Intentionally left blank
}

Friend::~Friend(void)
{
   //Intentionally left blank
}

void Friend::Test(Master* masterPtr)
{
   std::cout << masterPtr->largeData << std::endl;
}
```

I want class Friend to be able to share Master's private members. However, I can't get this code to compile. I've tried Forward Declaration, and #includes, but I start getting into circular dependencies. When Friend class is not a member of Master class, the code compiles?

Is it possible for Friend class be a member of Master and be friends? 
How else can Friend class have access to Masters private members?

Comment: What are the compiler errors. (C&P them)

Comment: If I use the code above: In file Master.h: error: 'Friend' does not name a type. If I #include "Friend.h" in Master.h, I get the an error in Friend.h: error: 'Master' has not been declared. Yet #include "Master.h" is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following includes and forward declarations:

In Master.h:

```
#include "Friend.h"
```

In Friend.h:

```
class Master;
```

In Friend.cpp:

```
#include "Master.h"
```

Putting the forward declaration in `Friend.h` prevents circular dependency. A forward declaration is enough there because you only declare a `Master*` parameter, without using its members yet.

You do need to include `Friend.h` from `Master.h` because you are declaring a `Friend` member, and this requires a complete type.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was struggling with circular dependencies, and I did try using forward declaration in Friend.h. The trick was the #include in Friend.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're struggling with circular dependencies.  Note that, to make something a `friend` you do not need to include it.  That said, in your `Master` class, you instantiate friend which requires its inclusion as a header (otherwise the compiler will be all WTF?).

However, in `friend.h` you can simply forward-declare the master class and not directly include it:

```
class Master;
```

This is because you are not attempting to instantiate the `Master` class, but use a pointer to it.